# Is the sIFR project dead?

Tags: css, flash, sifr, sifr3

I need to implement a typographic solution, and was about to go the sIFR route, but sIFR 2 is ancient and sIFR 3 doesn't appear to have been worked on in over a year and a half.

I've been looking into the `@font-face` method, but I'm pretty sure that the fonts I need to use do not allow web embedding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Truth is, I got bored with development, got busy with other things, and proper web fonts started becoming feasible. At this point I can't see myself going back and improving sIFR, there's just no point to it.

The reason it was never officially completed is that there was still work left to do, albeit not very critical work. However to make r436 official 19 months after the fact would be a bit silly.

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative, easier (imo) to use: http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/ and is 100% JavaScript based.

Comment: I've looked at Cufón, but the font license would need to allow for web embedding, right?

Comment: Yes, I've found cufon a nice alternative to sIFR. As an alternative, could you consider a subscription service, like the rather cool-looking Typekit? Never tried it myself, but: http://typekit.com/

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's actually "completed". Some projects simply reach a point, where there's nothing really left to add, because they completely fullfill their goals. This is very rare, but sIFR has a very concise objective, and there's not really anything left to enhance. There are 2 other projects I know of: MTASC and AMFPHP. Developement is discontinued, because there's nothing left to do, unless you want to change the nature of the project.

greetz
back2dos

Comment: A 'proper' release of sIFR 3 was never done, but you may be correct.

Comment: Close enough. Excuse me for commenting here, but I posted my personal views (as the developer) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850509/is-the-sifr-project-dead/2869474#2869474

Answer (score 2):

I guess with the advent of CSS3 fonts it isn't needed that much any more.

If licensing is your issue, I'm afraid sIFR has quite similar issues as CSS3 fonts. I suggest checking out http://typekit.com for good web accessible fonts.

Comment: Until CSS3 fonts are implemented in 99% of users' browsers, we're going to need a fallback.

Comment: Though I'm pretty sure that flash isn't the way to go (since it definitely isn't on 99% of browsers) - for a much better fallback solution see: http://www.awayback.com/revised-font-stack/

Comment: Some foundries have specific exemptions for sIFR, allowing you to use a font with sIFR where it wouldn't be allowed with Web Fonts.

Answer (score 2):

Another interesting option brand new from our friend Google: http://code.google.com/apis/webfonts/